# Is there a module that will let me set up site-wide notifications like Stack Overflow's orange one?

Tags: 7, users, notifications

I'm looking for a Drupal 7 compatible module that will let me set up site-wide notifications similar to Stack Overflow's orange bar (Welcome to this site, read the FAQ etc.). I haven't been able to find one.

Please note that I don't want to display **system** messages like this, I want something where **I** or other selected users can set up custom ones.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. To me it seems there are 2 parts to this question: A: how to display a bar with a message on top of the site. B: how to trigger those messages (from code, using rules, etc)

Comment: Yeah, that seems right. Maybe something with making a CCK defined page that gives you the option to flag it and enter a message. Then, in actions, when it notes that that page has been flagged, it displays the text field of that page in an otherwise invisible block that you set for the whole site? I'm not sure how clear that was, or if it will work.... I'll try it then post back.

Comment: It works badly -- it's too much of a hack for my taste. And wastes resources. I think a module should be created for this. I've just started trying to make one, although it's my first module. Help would be welcome.

Comment: that's great! Purr and set_message() is exactly what I needed. I think I just need to define a new message parameter (maybe "info") and give the user a simple ui to set one.

Comment: This thread is *way* old, but just for anyone else stumbling across this: the question states not wanting to display system messages, which is what the checked answer is all about.  For messages you can control and display to users, there are some other options which I've added to this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the list of modules for [Displaying Status Messages](http://groups.drupal.org/node/51088) — some of these might provide a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other options:

1. User Alert
   https://www.drupal.org/project/user_alert
2. Site Alert
   https://www.drupal.org/project/site_alert
3. Alerts
   https://www.drupal.org/project/alerts
4. Sitewide Alert Message
   https://www.drupal.org/project/sitewide_msg